# How to set up namespaces for Azure tts (mstts)

Tags: python, xml, xml-namespaces, elementtree

I need to create this header for Azure TTS:

```
 <speak version="1.0" 
  xmlns="https://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" 
   xmlns:mstts="https://www.w3.org/2001/mstts" 
   xml:lang="en-US">
```

This is the code that works to create the xml:lang key:

```
xml_body = ElementTree.Element('speak', version='1.0')
xml_body.set('{http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace}lang', 'en-us')
```

I've tried to create the xmlns:mstts without success. This doesn't work:

```
xml_body.set('{https://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis}mstts', 'https://www.w3.org/2001/mstts' )
```

because this produces the following output:

```xml
<speak
 xmlns:ns0="https://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis"
 version="1.0"
 xml:lang="en-us"
 ns0:mstts="https://www.w3.org/2001/mstts" />
```

Note the `xmlns:ns0` and `ns0:mstts` problems in the attributes on the `<speak>` element.

Any ideas?

Comment: *How* does in not work? What happens instead? What output do you see and what is wrong with that output?

Answer (score 6):

You need to give the `speak` element a namespace, as well as it's `version` attribute, that's what the `xmlns="..."` attribute normally configures. Use the `{<namespaceuri>}<tagname>` qualified name format for this, just like you do for the `xml:lang` attribute:

```
xml_body = ElementTree.Element('{https://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis}speak')
xml_body.set('{https://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis}version', '1.0')
xml_body.set('{http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace}lang', 'en-us')
```

You can also add the attributes as a dictionary, passed in as the second argument:

```
xml_body = ElementTree.Element(
    '{https://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis}speak', {
        '{https://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis}version': '1.0',
        '{http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace}lang': 'en-us'
    })
```

You do **not** need to set the `xmlns:mstts` attribute, however! ElementTree will add this attribute *automatically*, as needed, based on what namespaces have been used in the XML tree you build.

You *do* want to *register* this namespace with ElementTree, using the [`register_namespace()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.register_namespace):

```
ElementTree.register_namespace('mstts', 'https://www.w3.org/2001/mstts')
```

This tells ElementTree that when you use the `{https://www.w3.org/2001/mstts}` namespace with tag names or attributes, that *when serialising the XML tree to a file or string*, that this namespace should be using `mstts` as the prefix. If you *don't* register the namespace, a namespace prefix will be generated for you (`ns0:`, `ns1:`, etc.). That'll result in perfectly valid XML, namespace prefixes are documentation-local and prefixes are just short-hand names for the full namespace URI. Any compliant XML parser will handle `ns0` as the prefix for the `https://www.w3.org/2001/mstts` namespace URI exactly the same as using `mstts`.

For a *default* namespace (such as the `https://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis` namespace for the root `<speak>` element), use the `default_namespace` argument for the [`ElementTree.write()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write).

I find it easier to [`QName()` objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.QName) to handle namespaced attribute and tag names; together with variables for the specific namespaces that makes it less likely you make typos. Here is a more full-fledged example [based on an example from the Azure SSML documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speech-synthesis-markup)

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
from functools import partial

ns = {
    "synthesis": "https://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis",
    "mstts": "https://www.w3.org/2001/mstts",
    "xml": "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace",
}
ET.register_namespace('mstts', ns['mstts'])

synthesis = partial(ET.QName, ns["synthesis"])
mstts = partial(ET.QName, ns["mstts"])
xml_ = partial(ET.QName, ns["xml"])

xml_body = ET.Element(synthesis('speak'), {
    synthesis('version'): '1.0',
    xml_('lang'): 'en-us',
})
voice = ET.SubElement(xml_body, synthesis('voice'), {
    synthesis('name'): 'en-US-JessaNeural'})
express_as = ET.SubElement(voice, mstts('express-as'), {
    mstts('type'): 'cheerful'})
express_as.text = "That'd be just amazing!"

root = ET.ElementTree(xml_body)
root.write("filename.xml", encoding="UTF-8", default_namespace=ns["synthesis"])
```

The above produces the following XML (manually pretty-printed for easy reading):

```xml
<speak
 xmlns="https://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis"
 xmlns:mstts="https://www.w3.org/2001/mstts"
 version="1.0"
 xml:lang="en-us">
    <voice name="en-US-JessaNeural">
        <mstts:express-as mstts:type="cheerful">
            That'd be just amazing!
        </mstts:express-as>
    </voice>
</speak>
```

You may instead want to look at the [external `lxml` library](https://lxml.de/index.html) as well, as it includes an [`lxml.builder.ElementMaker` class](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#the-e-factory) that makes working with namespaces easier still.

lxml has much better namespace support in general, and attributes of an element that already has a namespace don't need to be explicitly qualified with a namespace themselves. You can mark a given namespace mapping as the default by using the prefix `None` in a dictionary setting up the namespaces:

```
from lxml import etree as ET
from lxml.builder import ElementMaker

ns = {
    None: "https://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis",
    "mstts": "https://www.w3.org/2001/mstts",
}

E = ElementMaker(namespace=ns[None], nsmap=ns)
TTS = ElementMaker(namespace=ns['mstts'])

xml_body = E.speak(
    {"version": "1.0",
     "{http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace}lang": "en-US"},
    E.voice(
        {"name": "en-US-JessaNeural"},
        TTS.express_as(
            "That'd be just amazing!",
            type="cheerful",
        )
    )
)
```

In the above, using either `E.tagname(...)` or `E('tagname', ...)` will create an element with the `https://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis` namespace URI, while the `MSTTS` object creates tags with the `https://www.w3.org/2001/mstts` namespace URI. Because we gave `E` a namespace map with `None` mapping to the `https://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis` namespace URI, that URI will be used as the default namespace and tagnames and attributes in that namespace will not be prefixed.

You can pass in attributes either as keyword arguments (`E.tagname(..., attributename="value")`) or via a dictionary passed in as positional argument. Any contained elements can simply be added as positional arguments, including text. You can also add the normal `Element` methods (e.g. `Element.append()` to add a child element, or `Element.text = ...` to set dictate what the text content of a tag is).

Demo using lxml:

```
>>> from lxml import etree as ET
>>> from lxml.builder import ElementMaker
>>> ns = {
...     None: "https://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis",
...     "mstts": "https://www.w3.org/2001/mstts",
... }
>>> E = ElementMaker(namespace=ns[None], nsmap=ns)
>>> TTS = ElementMaker(namespace=ns['mstts'])
>>> xml_body = E.speak(
...     {"version": "1.0",
...      "{http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace}lang": "en-US"},
...     E.voice(
...         {"name": "en-US-JessaNeural"},
...         TTS.express_as(
...             "That'd be just amazing!",
...             type="cheerful",
...         )
...     )
... )
>>> print(ET.tostring(xml_body, encoding="unicode", pretty_print=True))
<speak xmlns="https://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" xmlns:mstts="https://www.w3.org/2001/mstts" version="1.0" xml:lang="en-US">
  <voice name="en-US-JessaNeural">
    <mstts:express_as type="cheerful">That'd be just amazing!</mstts:express_as>
  </voice>
</speak>
```

Comment: I saw this entry first but it was deleted. It works for me and I find it easier:
`
 xml_body = ET.Element('speak', version='1.0', xmlns="https://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis")
 xml_body.set('{http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace}lang', 'en-us')
 xml_body.set('xmlns:mstts', 'https://www.w3.org/2001/mstts')
`

Comment: @rodbs: another user had posted an answer before me that was subsequently downvoted and the poster deleted it again. I gave feedback on that post; they were manually adding `xmlns:mstts` and `xml:lang` attributes, which actually breaks proper namespace handling.

Comment: @rodbs: it may *seem easier at first*, but it trivially leads to typos and errors that are hard to trace back.

Comment: I don't understand why if  i do:
  `body= ET.tostring(xml_body)`
   `print(body)`
I'm getting:
`<ns0:speak xmlns:mstts="https://www.w3.org/2001/mstts" 
 xmlns:ns0="https://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" 
 xml:lang="en-us" ns0:version="1.0">
 <ns0:voice ns0:name="en-US-JessaNeural">
  <mstts:express-as mstts:type="cheerful">
   That\'d be just amazing!
  </mstts:express-as>
 </ns0:voice>
</ns0:speak>`

Comment: @rodbs: The `ET.tostring()` function *doesn't handle default namespaces*. It just has no functionality for this. That's why I used `ET.ElementTree(xml_body).write()` instead.

Comment: @rodbs: If you use `lxml` instead, then using a `nsmap` dictionary argument with a `None` key lets you set the default namespace to be used for any part of the tree, because that library is just *so much better at namespace handling*. That's why I included a full `ElementMaker` example too.